# convert colour codes in R

Tags: r, excel, rgb

I have colour codes in the format  #0A68A6 or #0A428C and so on. Is there an easy way in R to convert them into long excel colour codes (for the examples above 10905600 and 9191946)?

Comment: i mainly want to use R because I don't know how I can apply a function to more than 1 cell in vba....and this is a huge problem if you have a 10 10 matrix

Answer (score 2):

Use `col2rgb` and multiply and sum:

```
> sum(col2rgb("#0A68A6") * c(1,256,256*256))
[1] 10905610
> sum(col2rgb("#0A428C") * c(1,256,256*256))
[1] 9191946
```

I get 10905610 not 10905600 for the first example, did you make a typo?

If you have a vector of colour codes, apply the sum along the second dimension:

```
> apply(col2rgb(c("#0A428C","#0A68A6")) * c(1,256,256*256), 2, sum)
[1]  9191946 10905610
```

Spose I should credit this link to how the long colour code number is defined:

http://www.garybeene.com/code/visual%20basic168.htm

And for didactic clarification, here's the thing broken down into parts:

`col2rgb` breaks the hexadecimal colour string into a matrix of decimal numbers, one column per colour with red, green and blue rows. Here both colours start with `#0A` which is hexadecimal for 10, so row 1 is two tens. The hexadecimal `42` in the first one is 4*16+2 = 66 so there's a 66 in the green row for that colour. Hex `A6` is `10x16 + 6` = 166 so the second colour's blue component in decimal is 166:

```
> col2rgb(c("#0A428C","#0A68A6"))
      [,1] [,2]
red     10   10
green   66  104
blue   140  166
```

Multiplying a matrix by a vector works column-wise, so we multiply red by 1, green by 256 and blue by 256*256 like this:

```
> col2rgb(c("#0A428C","#0A68A6")) * c(1, 256, 256*256)
         [,1]     [,2]
red        10       10
green   16896    26624
blue  9175040 10878976
```

Now the excel colour code for a hex colour is the sum of the column:

```
> apply(col2rgb(c("#0A428C","#0A68A6")) * c(1, 256, 256*256), 2, sum)
[1]  9191946 10905610
```

Comment: does you rlast line also work with a matrix if I use 1:2 dimension?

Comment: I don't understand. `col2rgb` returns a matrix with r,g,b rows, each colour in a column (try it). The multiply does the scaling by multiplying each row by 1, 256, and 65536 (try it). Then the apply adds it up along the columns to get the sum which is the final answer.